# How do splitting fields over different field extensions "fit" inside each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose $F'/F$ is a field extension. And suppose $f \in F[x]$ is a polynomial. Then $f \in F'[x]$ of course.

So now we may consider two splitting fields for $f$: $K$ over $F$, and $K'$ over $F'$. How does $Gal(K'/F')$ relate to $Gal(K/F)$.

In particular, can we embed $Gal(K'/F')$ into $Gal(K/F)$? How does one construct the homomorphism?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: My approach was to try and draw a comparison between the roots wrt $K'$ and wrt $K$. Some of the roots in $K$ may already have their counterpart in $F'$ before being in $K'$, which is why $Gal(K'/F')$ is smaller than $Gal(K/F)$. But this correspondence between roots is not immediate to me.